# Xcode stuck on "Attaching to <MyApp>" only when a debugger is selected in the scheme

Tags: debugging, versioning, simulator, ipa, archiving

Overall goal: Build an ipa for use in testflight

Issue: When I go to archive and build the ipa, xcode gets hung up on the part where it says "Archiving ", i go and try to run on the simulator and lo and behold it won't work there either.  So i follow some troubleshooting steps and now it will run in the simulator but only if debugger is set to "none".  What causes this and how can I fix it?

Note: Everything was working fine initially until i tried to change the version somewhere from 1.0 to 1.1 or 1.2. Tried backtracking to no avail.

I have tried:

- Restarting the simulator
- Resetting simulator content and settings
- Rebooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got what works, If I turned off my network connection it would build and run no problem.  Must have had the keychain tied up somehow.